# C++ 11 passing shared_pointer like with std::any

Tags: c++11, templates, pointers, boost, any

at the moment I'm facing following problem. I need a member function in a derived class that can handle different shared_ptr types and do custom stuff with it. The base class should make sure that such a member function is implemented but the specific shared_ptr types are only known when a other developer create a new derived class. Therefore, templates are not a solution due to the fact that c++ not support virtual template functions.

The shared_ptrs hold protobuf message specific publisher or subscriber. Here a snipped of code:

```
std::shared_ptr<Publisher<ProtobufMessageType1>> type1 = std::make_shared<ProtobufMessageType1>();
std::shared_ptr<Publisher<ProtobufMessageType2>> type2 = std::make_shared<ProtobufMessageType2>();

class derived : base
{

  void takeThePointerAndDoSpecificStuff( std::shared_ptr<PubOrSub<SpecificProtobufMessage>>) override
  {
     // check type and bind specific callback
  }
}
```

One solution could be casting shared_ptr to base class but it is not possible because the protobuf message base class is pure virtual. Another solution is to cast the raw pointer and only transfer this one but I need the share_ptr reference count also in the method ( due to binding).

So I look further for a solution and std::any could be one but the problem here is that c++11 not have a std::any (sure could use boost but I try to avoid that).

So now I'm out of ideas how to solve the problem but perhaps you have one and can help me.

Thank you for any answer in advance.

Comment: I think you should refine the concept that `base` is supposed to represent. If you come up with a more clear specification for it, then it may be possible to implement this more naturally without running up against limitations of templates and virtual functions.

Right now the spec is very vague: "Take a `shared_ptr` to one of several possible template classes, and do 'custom stuff' with it"

Comment: Do you want instances of this concept to:

- Be able to take a shared_ptr to AT LEAST ONE instance of a template class coming from one of these types
- Be able to take a shared_ptr to ANY instantiation of one of these (publisher or subscriber) template classes

What exactly is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One solution could be casting shared_ptr to base class but it is not possible because the protobuf message base class is pure virtual

That's simply not true. You can have shared pointers to abstract bases just fine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d925f3c375f63bf)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

struct D1 : Base { virtual void foo() const override { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } };
struct D2 : Base { virtual void foo() const override { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } };

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> b = std::make_shared<D1>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> c = std::make_shared<D2>();

    b->foo();
    c->foo();
}
```

Prints

```
virtual void D1::foo() const
virtual void D2::foo() const
```

### More Ideas

Even in case you do not **have** a common base (or a base at all) you can still use `shared_pointer`. One particularly powerful idiom is to use `shared_pointer<void>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc8324a81f536bd4)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct D1 { 
    void foo() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    ~D1()            { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};
struct D2 {
    void bar() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    ~D2()            { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<void> b = std::make_shared<D1>();
    std::shared_ptr<void> c = std::make_shared<D2>();

    std::static_pointer_cast<D1>(b)->foo();
    std::static_pointer_cast<D2>(c)->bar();
}
```

Prints

```
void D1::foo() const
void D2::bar() const
D2::~D2()
D1::~D1()
```

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#techniques_using_shared_ptr_void_to_hold_an_arbitrary_object

Comment: If your types _are_ polymorphic (`protobuf::Message` _is_) you can of course [use `dynamic_pointer_cast<>` to detect the actual type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2413fe11f6e5776) and, yes, you can [combine that with the `void` pointer approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/604d827d07aea289)

Comment: Mhh ok I will try to cast my shared_ptr<Pub<protobufMessage>> to shared_ptr<void> hopefully it is possible